# How to Delete item from cart if quanity less than 0 . Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My problem is that the item is not removed from cart when quantity is less than 0 and also quantity is going -1,-2 etc. Can you help me?

**This is my controller**

```
 public function reducequantity(Request $request){
    $id = $_GET['id']; 
    $oldcart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
    $cart = new Cart($oldcart);
    $cart->reducequantity($id);
    Session::put('cart',$cart);      
    echo json_encode("item reduced from cart");
    }
```

**This is my model**

```
    public function reducequantity($id){       
        $this->items[$id]['qty']--;
        $this->items[$id]['price'] -=  $this->items[$id]['item']['price'];
        $this->totalqty--;
        $this->total_price -=  $this->items[$id]['item']['price'];
        if($this->items[$id]['qty'] <= 0){ 
            unset($this->items[$id]);
        }       
   }
```

Comment: It looks to me like you have different sources of 'carts' namely, `$this->items` and `Session`. If that is correct, then you'll have the headache of getting both in sync. Why not simply, pass the current whole cart data into `reducequantity()` for example `reducequantity($id, $cart)` then you modify it and return it to the calling function. I think making the process a clearer to understand will help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    **Solved By making a little change in controller**
    public function removeitem(Request $request){
     $id = $_GET['id']; 
     $oldcart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
     $cart = new Cart($oldcart);
      $cart->removeitem($id);
       if(count($cart->items) > 0){
         Session::put('cart',$cart);
     }else{
        Session::forget('cart');
     }

      echo json_encode("item removed");
}
```